# How to implement "Reshape Effect" on image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, image-manipulation

In my IOS app . i need to implement "Reshape Effect" on image. i searched a lot but but didn't get desired effect . i need to such effect on panning in image.

[image: Normal Image]

[image: After desired effect]

Comment: [link](http://code4app.net/ios/Image-reshape/518768256803fa0407000003) try this.

Comment: i hope this will help you https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: thanks for answer - @spynet  , i used  this before but didn't work as required .