# Image effect(reshape)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage

I want to create function(reshape). User can interact with image by touching and reshape the image.
I found question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149251/how-to-implement-reshape-effect-on-image) but there was no answer...

Maybe someone can tell me where I can find the answer fro this question? or what I have to read for this?

Comment: is this true http://code4app.net/ios/Image-reshape/518768256803fa0407000003 ?

Comment: Swift / Objective-C ? Where is your code ?

Comment: @HuyNghia, it means I can implement this functions with OpenGL ES?

Comment: @Raptor no code because I have no idea how to implement this, maybe I specified incorrectly tags

Comment: Learn either of the language and try coding first .

Answer (score 1):

This is the link for your question [link](http://code4app.net/ios/Image-reshape/518768256803fa0407000003) . Refer this you can get some idea. Make sure you have xcode 6.  [image: simulator output]

Comment: Is this useful, If this answer was useful please mark as correct.